# List all users who have access to LEAP support and LEAP development subscription in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

I want to find out the below with power shell, Please help me.

List all users who have access to LEAP support and LEAP development subscription in Azure

Comment: See [ask]. You need to do some research and give it a try. This reads like you want us to write this solution for you.

Comment: What is LEAP? As written, it's unclear what you're asking. Also, regarding PowerShell: What have you done so far? Where are you stuck? Without specifics, this question is both "unclear" and "too broad" (hence off-topic). Please edit to be specific.